# Weird instance variable glitch in Ruby

Tags: ruby

look at this
(Edited with less sloppy code)

```
class Numeric
    @@currencies = {'dollar' => 1, 'yen' => 0.013, 'euro' => 1.292, 'rupee' => 0.019}
    attr_writer :previous_currency
    def method_missing(method_id)
        singular_currency = method_id.to_s.gsub( /s$/, '')
        if @@currencies.has_key?(singular_currency)
            @previous_currency = singular_currency
            self * @@currencies[singular_currency]
        else
            super
        end
    end

    def in(currency)
        singular_currency = currency.to_s.gsub( /s$/, '')
        rate = @@currencies[singular_currency]
        if @@currencies[@previous_currency] < rate
            self / rate
        else
            self * rate
        end
    end
end
```

This extension to the Numeric class permits to do the following :

```
<Number>.<currency>.in(:<other_currency>)
```

like `5.dollars.in(:euros)`

If I have `dollars` as my first missing method, it works just fine. `@previous_currency` gets the value `dollar` at the first shot, then at the call of the missing method `in`, it retains its value and does the conversion just fine. But if I try anything else instead of `dollars` or `dollar`, `@previous_currency` somehow loses its value, becoming `nil` again at the call of `in` , resulting in the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method ` for nil:NilClass
```

I tried to switch dollar's place in the `@@currencies` hash, but the same behavior happens again.

Does Ruby loves dollars more ?

Comment: This is a super sloppy way of writing this btw. Why not just define an `in` method, instead of relying on `method_missing`? As written, you can do `5.dollars.viugdkaugehtkauge(:euros)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to maintain state on a number, and then returning some completely different number.

With dollars, `5.dollars` returns `5`, because you're naively assuming that "1" really means "1 dollar", (so why even use `1.dollar` when you could just use `1.in(:euros)`?), so 5 has an `@previous_currency` of `dollar`. `5.dollars` returns the *same object*, `5`, with the extra state you've attached to it.

With `euros`, `5.euros` returns `6.46`, which is a totally different object. It shares no state with the object `5`, so `@previous_currency` hasn't been set.

In order to make this work, you need to stop maintaining state and just always return the result *in dollars*, the same way `5.weeks`, `5.months`, and `5.years` return a number of seconds. Then you have a simple, stateless number. You should also stop relying on `method_missing`, and just dynamically define the methods. Here's a simple working version:

```
class Numeric
  @@currencies = {dollars: 1, yen: 0.013, euros: 1.292, rupees: 0.019}

  def in(currency)
    self / @@currencies[currency.to_sym]
  end

  @@currencies.keys.each do |method_name|
    define_method method_name do
      self * @@currencies[method_name.to_sym]
    end
  end
end

puts 1.euros # 1.292
puts 1.euros.in(:dollars) # 1.292
puts 1.dollars # 1
puts 1.dollars.in(:euros) # 0.7739938080495355


puts 1.euros.in(:yen) # 99.38461538461539
puts 1.euros.in(:dollars).in(:yen).in(:dollars) 99.38461538461539
```